# Ubuntu upgrade froze

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, 18.04

During an upgrade of Ubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04, the system  suddenly froze.

After a restart the system entering the correct password, it won't let me log in.

Rebooting again doesn't help.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Fresh install 18.04 and restore your data from backup

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the only thing to do now is to:

- Restore the system backup you took before you started the upgrade.

If you have none:

- Boot an Ubuntu 18.04 Live DVD/USB
- Use that one to back up your Documents, Videos, ...
- Reinstall
- Reboot

If all data is gone:

- Restore the backup you just made.